# memcpy for class-level array in copy constructor leads to segfault

Tags: c++, g++, memory-management, memcpy

There is a template class for sequences in 4-letter alphabet (=> 2 bits per letter):

```
template <size_t _size>
class Seq {
private:
    const static size_t _byteslen = (_size / 4) + (_size % 4 != 0);
    char _bytes[_byteslen];
public:
    Seq() {};
    Seq(const char* s);
    Seq(const Seq<_size> &seq);
    ...
    std::string str() const;
    ...
}
```

If copy constructor is implemented as silly from-to-string, then everything works OK.

```
Seq(const Seq<_size> &seq) {
    Seq(seq.str().c_str());
}
```

Otherwise, if copy constructor uses memcpy like that:

```
Seq(const Seq<_size> &seq) {
    memcpy(_bytes, seq._bytes, _byteslen);
}
```

The program gets segfault few seconds later (doing += or [] operations with totally different std::string). What can be a problem with such memcpy? Thank you.

P.S. memmove doesn't help.

Comment: You don't even need a user-declared/defined copy ctor. Apart from that, I see no error. You have probably undefined behaviour somewhere else.

Comment: Using `std::vector` or its new fixed-size equivalent `std::array` instead of manually copying memory is strongly recommended.

Comment: Making use of the compiler-generated copy ctor is strongly recommended.

Comment: Compiler-generated copy ctor does the same segfault.

Comment: You need to post the lines of code where the segfault is occurring. Aside from using underscore prefixes (identifiers beginning with underscores are reserved for the compiler), there is nothing wrong with the code that you posted.

Comment: Perhaps a missing null character at the end of _bytes (destination) is the problem ??

Comment: What did your debugger (`gdb`) say about the fault? It could be anything, including code that you did not post.

Comment: Did you run the stack trace ?? Output from stack-trace gives good cues..

Comment: What does `Seq::str` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"If copy constructor is implemented as silly from-to-string, then everything works OK."

```
Seq(const Seq<_size> &seq) {
    Seq(seq.str().c_str());
}
```

Really?  Because that constructor doesn't initialize `_bytes[]` at all.  (Instead, it creates a different temporary `Seq` object, which is unused and immediately destroyed.)

Comment: Thank you. Well, the point is that it doesn't crash the whole program, while memcpy does.

Comment: @Nikolay: The symptoms of UB are not reliable. Don't get trapped into thinking that just because you don't get a crash without a `memcpy` line the rest of your program is ok. UB only results in a crash under certain fortuitous (and largely unpredictable) circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: your str() function returns _bytes as a string, trying to build that from a buffer that is not nul terminated.